# How to set auto-generated created_at/updated_at fields to mongodb collection with golang mongo-driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

Currently, I handle the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields myself, as part of the application logic.

I'm now using [multi-document transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/transactions/?_ga=2.83330399.876438863.1654091816-1779239596.1638477453) for a bulk upsert: from the `n` documents specified, those which already exist in the collection are only updated, and those which doesn't, are inserted.

The problem is when an already existing document is updated, it's `created_at` field is updated too with the current date, which is incorrect for my business logic. If I don't specify a `created_at` field in this operation, then updated documents are fine, but the newly inserted ones are left without their creation time.

Having the driver/database itself deciding when to set both `created_at` and `updated_at` would be a solution since it is the driver/database itself who knows what kind of operation is being performed on each document.

With `Node.js` you can do the following:

```
schema.set('timestamps', true);
```

And `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields will be automatically added to your schema and managed by mongo.

But I haven't been able to find something similar for the [MongoDB Go Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/).

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Use upsert, with $setOnInsert https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/ for created_at field.